# Netty - Ignore failed setting of IP_TOS

Tags: java, netty

My users are reporting this error to me, and I would like to silently ignore it, since it is a non crucial part of my application.

> 2013-02-09 15:20:15 [WARNING] Failed to set a channel option: [id: 0x8cf59443, /84.100.204.150:51292 => /87.98.181.225:22091]
>   io.netty.channel.ChannelException: java.net.SocketException: Invalid argument: no further information
>       at io.netty.channel.socket.DefaultSocketChannelConfig.setTrafficClass(DefaultSocketChannelConfig.java:264)
>       at io.netty.channel.socket.DefaultSocketChannelConfig.setOption(DefaultSocketChannelConfig.java:115)
>       at io.netty.bootstrap.ServerBootstrap$ServerBootstrapAcceptor.inboundBufferUpdated(ServerBootstrap.java:264)
>       at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelHandlerContext.invokeInboundBufferUpdated(DefaultChannelHandlerContext.java:1170)
>       at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelHandlerContext.fireInboundBufferUpdated0(DefaultChannelHandlerContext.java:1148)
>       at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelHandlerContext.fireInboundBufferUpdated(DefaultChannelHandlerContext.java:1127)
>       at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireInboundBufferUpdated(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:903)
>       at io.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioMessageChannel$NioMessageUnsafe.read(AbstractNioMessageChannel.java:84)
>       at io.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:397)
>       at io.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:361)
>       at io.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:301)
>       at io.netty.channel.SingleThreadEventExecutor$2.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:110)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
>   Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Invalid argument: no further information
>       at sun.nio.ch.Net.setIntOption0(Native Method)
>       at sun.nio.ch.Net.setSocketOption(Unknown Source)
>       at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.setOption(Unknown Source)
>       at sun.nio.ch.SocketAdaptor.setIntOption(Unknown Source)
>       at sun.nio.ch.SocketAdaptor.setTrafficClass(Unknown Source)
>       at io.netty.channel.socket.DefaultSocketChannelConfig.setTrafficClass(DefaultSocketChannelConfig.java:262)
>       ... 12 more

To accomplish this, I am simply setting the `IP_TOS` option in my `ServerBootstrap`:
`childOption(ChannelOption.IP_TOS, 0x18)`

If you know where I would need to place a handler, or option to ignore a failure in setting this option, please let me know.

md_5

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's an example bootstrap code that sets an option:

```
        Bootstrap b = new Bootstrap();
        b.group(new NioEventLoopGroup(), new NioEventLoopGroup())
         .channel(NioServerSocketChannel.class)
         .option(ChannelOption.SO_BACKLOG, 100)
         .handler(new LoggingHandler(LogLevel.INFO))
         .childHandler(new ChannelInitializer<SocketChannel>() {
             @Override
             public void initChannel(SocketChannel ch) throws Exception {
                 try {
                     ch.config().setTrafficClass(0x18);
                 } catch (ChannelException e) {
                     // Ignore
                 }
                 ch.pipeline().addLast(
                         new LoggingHandler(LogLevel.INFO),
                         new EchoServerHandler());
             }
         });
```